# Working with 8-bit image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, data-quality

I'm working with the MODIS Terra Continuous Fields 250m product. The data include several bands, including a "Quality" band.

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Rwanda"));

var data = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD44B')
.map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});

var quality00 = data.filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31'))
.select("Quality").toBands()
```

The quality band is an 8-bit image, and the quality assessment is based on the raw imagery being cloudy, high aerosol, cloud shadow, or view zenith greater than 45 degrees. [MODIS recommends](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/459/MOD44B_User_Guide_V5.pdf) masking out any images in which the quality was bad "for 2 or more of the 8 time periods".

The MODIS documentation describes the bits as follows: from their documentation I suspect these are the 8 underlying images being quality-assessed, but I am not sure.

- Bit 0: State of input layers DOY 065-097: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 1: State of input layers DOY 113-145: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 2: State of input layers DOY 161-193: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 3: State of input layers DOY 209-241: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 4: State of input layers DOY 257-289: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 5: State of input layers DOY 305-337: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 6: State of input layers DOY 353-017: 0: Clear, 1: Bad
- Bit 7: State of input layers DOY 033-045: 0: Clear, 1: Bad

I'm not sure how to take this layer to identify the pixels with low quality in a given year. If the values were numeric (out of 8) then I would expect that any value greater than 2 gets flagged. But that's not how the data are organized: the minimum value of the quality band is 0 and the maximum is 255.

How do you use this 8-bit image to identify low quality pixels?

UPDATE: I've found some user support to help me figure out the binary data structure. [This tutorial](https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/08/19/qa-bands-bitmasks-gee/) was very useful. The one thing I still am trying to figure out: how do I make an image where each grid-cell reports the count of bits that were 1? For example, if the binary code is 01001100, then the value for that grid-cell should be 3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ee.Image.bitCount` counts the number of bits set in each pixel.

```
var count = image.bitCount()
```

Comment: Thank you for offering a tip! I just tried this using the quality00 variable, but the output still has a maximum value of 255 instead of 8. Is there something I may have done wrong?

Comment: Ah, maybe the image stores the former image's properties? I just rendered a histogram and the maximum value in the variable count is 8. Finally cracked it! Thank you so much!!